# Accessing shared preferences of another application

Tags: android

I am trying to access the shared preferences of another application using this code:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> LIST = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Context myContext = null;
            try {
                myContext = createPackageContext("owning app's pkg name", 
                Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // where com.example is the owning  app containing the  preferences
              @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            SharedPreferences testPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences 
            ("file", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); 


            Map<String, ?> items = testPrefs .getAll();
            System.out.println(items.size());
            for(String s : items.keySet())
            {
                //do somthing like String value=     items.get(s).toString());
                System.out.println(items.get(s).toString());
                }
```

However I am getting the size as 0 of the map "items". This is the stack trace:

```
12-04 12:24:13.659: W/SharedPreferencesImpl(22768): Attempt to read preferences file   /data/data/owning app's pkg name/shared_prefs/filename.xml without permission
12-04 12:24:13.659: I/System.out(22768): 0
```

It indicates that the owning app doesn't support the sharing. Is there any way I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

owning application needs to have mode WORLD_READABLE permission.
Additionally you have to add same android:sharedUserId in the both app's manifest file.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have that permission. Any way to bypass this? Also what does CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY do, and why does it not work in this case?

Comment: try changing your owning shared pref mode this way    SharedPreferences testPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences 
                    ("sharedprefone", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: which api you are using??because world_ readable/writable is deprecated from api17

Comment: yea its deprecated for me. Anything else I can use?